# Convert raw YOLO output to bounding boxes

Tags: yolo

I'm trying to convert the raw output of my tiny yoloV3-model to bounding box coordinates. My input is a 416x416-image and the raw output has shape `[2535, 6]`, corresponding to `[center_x,  center_y,  width,  height,  obj score,  class prob.]` for each box. I want to convert the first four elements of this array into actual pixel coordinates, but I'm not sure how to interpret the values. As an example, most arrays look something like this:

`[-4.3124937e+03 -4.5493687e+03  4.7279790e+03  5.0129067e+03 9.9985057e-01  9.9992472e-01]`

Why are the values for `center_x` and `center_y` negative? And why is `width` and `height` so large?